# Load image coming from Server on Canvas

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file, canvas, fabricjs

I have a designer application in FabricJS. Designer view is being loaded from my Controller action. I am passing an image path with view model to my view.

How can i load this image from path on to my canvas for manipulations.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
function UploadArtwork() {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            App.renderImageFromUrl(reader.result, function (image) {
                caseApp.getCanvas().setActiveObject(image);
                }
            });
            event.currentTarget.value = null;
        };

         reader.readAsDataURL('@file');
        }
    }
```

And i am reading file like this:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
    var file = webClient.DownloadData(artwork.ArtworkPath);
```

Its not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why aren't you just using fabric.Image.fromURL?

Comment: @JohnM Thank you. I figured it out after posting this stupid question. I believe i didn't have breakfast and my mind was way off the cliff. :)